# Why can't I send friend invites?

Tags: steam

I can't invite anyone to be my friend. It says select all but there's nothing there. Why can't I send any friend invites?

Comment: Did you buy at least one game?

Comment: As @Vemonus said, I think you need to spend at least 5 bucks to unlock that feature of Steam.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't provided enough information about this, I'm going to assume that your account is classified as a [Limited User Account](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3330-IAGK-7663).

Your account will be classified as such until you've spent $5 in the Steam store. It's very important that the $5 was spent *in the Steam store*. From the linked page:

> You will need to spend at least $5.00 USD within the Steam store.
>
> Some examples of purchases that grant access to these features are:
>
> - Adding the equivalent of $5 USD or more to your Steam Wallet
> - Purchasing game(s) that are equal to $5 USD or more from the Steam store
> - Adding a Steam Wallet card that is equal to $5 USD or more to your Steam account
> - Purchasing a Steam gift that is equal to $5 USD or more from the Steam store (Receiving a Steam gift from a friend doesn't count)
>
> Each Steam purchase total will be tracked in USD. If your Steam store's currency isn't in USD, it will be tracked and converted to USD automatically using daily exchange rates.

As a Limited User, the following features are unavailable to you:

> - **Sending friend invites**
> - Opening group chat
> - Voting on Greenlight, Steam Reviews and Workshop items
> - Participating in the Steam Market
> - Posting frequently in the Steam Discussions
> - Gaining Steam Profile Levels (Locked to level 0) and Trading Cards
> - Submitting content on the Steam Workshop
> - Posting in an item's Steam Workshop Discussions
> - Accessing the Steam Web API
> - Using browser and mobile chat
> - Adding public artwork and screenshots
> - Creating Steam groups